# Ant media webrtc connecting to server gives java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException

Tags: android, webrtc, ant-media-server-sdk, webrtc-android

I'm trying to connect to Ant media webrtc server `wss://abcd.com:1234/demoApp/websocket`. However it always throws.

```
de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter: Socket is closed
```

I'm using ant media webrtc framework sample android example and changing the URL. It worked fine with test server of antmedia

```
wss://test.antmedia.io:5443/demo1234/websocket(URL changed for security purposes)
```

However I was never able to connect to the main server. This is the code at android which I'm using to connect with server.

```
webRTCClient = WebRTCClient(this@LiveSessionActivity, this)
webRTCClient.setVideoRenderers(mLiveSessionBinding?.pipViewRenderer, mLiveSessionBinding?.localGLSurfaceView)
webRTCClient.init(ANT_MEDIA_URL, mLiveSessionViewModel?.streamKey, IWebRTCClient.MODE_PUBLISH, "null", intent)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's known issue in v2.2.1. You need to set chain.pem file to Ant Media Server. Here are the instructions:

Copy chain.pem to conf.

```
sudo cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/your_domain/chain.pem /usr/local/antmedia/conf
```

> PS: Please change your_domain to your domain address.

**1- Add this line**

```
http.ssl_certificate_chain_file=conf/chain.pem
```

after

```
http.ssl_certificate_file=conf/fullchain.pem
```

in `/usr/local/antmedia/conf/red5.properties` file.

**2- Add this line**

```
<entry key="SSLCertificateChainFile" value="${http.ssl_certificate_chain_file}" />
```

after

```
<entry key="SSLCertificateFile" value="${http.ssl_certificate_file}" />
```

in `/usr/local/antmedia/conf/jee-container.xml` file